# Как работать с элементами(Label, TextView и т.д), контроллера из другого класса(не из другой сцены, а из другого класса!)

Tags: java, javafx, controller

Как работать с элементами(Label, TextView и т.д), контроллера из другого класса (не из другой сцены, а из другого класса!)

Допустим я не хочу работать в Controller-е, так как это не удобно. Я подготовил небольшой проект, у меня есть сценка, где при нажатии кнопки, он считывает это нажатие в Controllere и передаёт обработку уже в другой класс Test.java, где есть метод test(), он меняет `LabelTest("Тест")`, на `("Тест прошёл успешно")`. Но появляется ошибка `NullPointerException`.

Код:

```
package application;
    
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            java.net.URL fxmlURL = getClass().getResource("xmlFiles/oneOkon.fxml");
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(fxmlURL);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello world");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Label LabelTest;

    public Label getLabelTest() {
        return LabelTest;
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void buttonTest(ActionEvent event) {
        Test.test();
    }
}
```

```
package application;

public class Test {
    
    public static void test() {
        MainController t = new MainController();
        t.getLabelTest().setText("Тест прошёл успешно");
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <top>
      <Label fx:id="LabelTest" prefHeight="76.0" prefWidth="503.0" text="Тест" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </top>
   <center>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonTest" prefHeight="187.0" prefWidth="526.0" text="Проверка" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот экземпляр MainController, который создан в Test.test() не имеет ничего общего с тем, который отвечает за то, что на экране.

У вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. Передать в метод test Consumer

   ```
    new Consumer<String>() {
      @Override  
      public void accept(String s) {  
        LabelTest.setText(s);  
    }});
   ```

А уже в самом методе тест, передать нужную строку

```
    public void test(Consumer<String> consumer) {
      consumer.accept("Тест прошёл успешно");
    }
```

Могут возникнуть осложнения, если сам тест будет проходить в другом потоке, но это уже другой вопрос.

2. Если test() исполняется синхронно, то самое простое вернуть из него результат исполнения в качестве строки или более сложного объекта и уже в контроллере присвоить этот результат в LabelTest

   ```
    @FXML
    public void buttonTest(ActionEvent event) {
      LabelTest.setText(Test.test());
    }

   public String test() {
      // Do Job
      return "Тест прошёл успешно";
    }
   ```
3. Самый топорный вариант это в тест передать сам контроллер. Если вы это делаете в качестве какого-то задания, то избегайте такой вариант.

   ```
    @FXML
    public void buttonTest(ActionEvent event) {
      Test.test(this);
    }

    public static void test(MainController t) {
      t.getLabelTest().setText("Тест прошёл успешно");
    }
   ```

У Fx так же есть классы `SimpleStringProperty` и подобные. Можно привязать значение текста в LabelTest к значению SimpleStringProperty и передавать/менять его. Чем-то похоже на первый вариант.